# What do you use Git and SVN for?

Tags: git, svn

What is are Git and SVN good for?

I see lots of people talking about them, but I don't see how they are helpful.
Are they just places to store your code online?
Would they help me to complete my programs faster?

I am working alone, not with a group.

Comment: Git and SVN are two different revision control systems. Are you asking about using then together, or are you asking about using revision control systems in general?

Comment: I've edited your question on the assumption that you're *not* asking about using Git and SVN together (as implied by the answer you accepted). Feel free to revert my edit if I've changed the meaning of your question. (And please see the question that yours has been flagged as a duplicate of.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Git and SVN are version control systems. They help can work as an "undo" for people working alone. Modifications you make over time will be saved. You can also create alternate branches of code, and then merge them back with the main branch. This can help you experiment with other ideas without disrupting the main project, for instance.

With a group, it allows many people to work on the same code at once. Their changes can merge without overwriting others'.

It is crucial to learn version control, and not hard. Your IDE (programming software) likely has controls built in. Git is the most popular and used on Github.

Answer (score -1):

Version control systems like git (and svn) are also very helpful when working alone.
They allow you to track what you changed, when you changed it and why you changed it. It gives you a history of you changes and allows you to restore any older version of your files.

For example you can use it for config files. Instead of making a lot of backup files it is much easier to store the older versions in you version control. If things break immediately you have an easy undo. If things break later you have a history of your changes and you can identify the bad change.

Especially git also allows you to write better code by letting you concentrate on the actual changes you do. - Think of building you code as a sequence of functional changes, which is much more understandable than only the final code.

Comment: Why the -1? Is there any problem with the answers?